# Github API: Getting different result every call. Trying to pull the most starred python repositories

Tags: python, json, github, python-requests, github-api

I am a newer programmer and I am trying to call the Github API to get a list of the most starred python projects, ordered by number of stars. Every time I run the program, rerunning the request, I am never getting the same result. Throwing everything into a dataframe and sorting by number of stars, every run of the program is giving me a different number. I'm not sure if I am doing something wrong with my code or not understanding the github api.

````
```
query_url = "https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=language:python&sort=stars&order=desc"


headers = {'Authorization': f'token {API_KEY}'}
r = requests.get(query_url, headers=headers)
result = r.json() # pprint(r.json())
```
````

Answer (score 1):

how about if using pagination and breaking it down into several pages? i think the Github API there's a parameter to achieve this using `per_page` and `page` parameters such as :

```py
import requests


def get_most_starred_python(page=None, per_page=None):
    base_url = "https://api.github.com/search/repositories"
    params = {
        "q": "language:python",
        "sort": "stars",
        "order": "desc",
        "page": page,
        "per_page": per_page,
    }

    resp = requests.get(base_url, params)
    data = resp.json()
    return data.get("items", [])

# by default if it was set to None, the page number would be set to 1
# and the per_page would be set to 30 but you can adjust accordingly your needs
all_repos = get_most_starred_python(page=1, per_page=20)
for repo in all_repos:
    print(f"Name of repo: {repo['name']}")
    print(f"Number of stars: {repo['stargazers_count']}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem: Pagination

Solution: Sort through all pages
Code:

```
def fetch_all_pages(url, headers):
    all_items = []
    page = 1
    while True:
        response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params={'q': 'language:python', 'sort': 'stars', 'order': 'desc', 'page': page})
        if response.status_code != 200:
            print(f"Error: {response.status_code}")
            return None
        
        result = response.json()
        items = result.get('items', [])
        
        if not items:
            break
        
        all_items.extend(items)
        page += 1
        
    return all_items
```